# JQuery not ignoring fields

Tags: jquery

I am unable to make jQuery ignore certain fields. According to documentation all should be ok but it's not.

Both default and specific settings are set to ingore elements with .ignore class:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('form').validate({
        ignore: '.ignore', 
        rules: {
            //tenant
            'firstName': { required: true, minlength: 2 },
            'lastName': { required: true, minlength: 2},
            'email': { required: true, email: true },
            'phone': { required: true, digits: true},
            'password': { required: true,  minlength: 5 },

          //apartment
            'intercom': { required: true,digits: true, minlength: 4, maxlength: 4},
            'apartmentNumber': { required: true, digits: true},
            'description': { required: true },
            //meters
            'description': { required: true},
            'serialNumber': { required: true},
            'unit': { required: true },
            'apartment': { required: true },
           //invoice
            'serialNumber': { required: true},
            'totalAmount': { required: true, number: true}
```

And de default settings:

```
$.extend($.validator, {

    defaults: {
        messages: {},
        groups: {},
        rules: {},
        errorClass: "error",
        validClass: "valid",
        errorElement: "label",
        focusInvalid: true,
        errorContainer: $( [] ),
        errorLabelContainer: $( [] ),
        onsubmit: true,
        ignore: ".ignore, :hidden",
        ignoreTitle: false,
        onfocusin: function(element, event) {
            this.lastActive = element;
```

Here is login page and for obvious reasons I would like to turn off validation for password. As act of desperation I started to insert "ignore" class in every single element hoping for it to finally work:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Login page</title>
<link class="row" href="<c:url value='/static/css/bootstrap.css' />"
    rel="stylesheet">

<link class="row" href="<c:url value='/static/css/style.css' />"
    rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value='/static/js/jquery-2.2.0.js' />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value='/static/js/bootstrap.js' />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value='/static/js/jquery.validate.js' />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='/static/js/jq.js' />"></script>



<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='jumbotron'>
                <h1>Kamienica</h1>
                <h3>Podaj login i hasło</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>

            <div class="login-container">
                <div class="login-card ignore">
                    <div class="form ignore">
                        <c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login" />
                        <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post"
                            class="form-horizontal form ignore">
                            <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <p>Invalid username and password.</p>
                                </div>
                            </c:if>
                            <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
                                <div class="alert alert-success">
                                    <p>You have been logged out successfully.</p>
                                </div>
                            </c:if>
                            <div class="input-group input-sm">
                                <label class="input-group-addon ingore" for="email"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-user ignore"></i></label> <input type="text"
                                    class="ignore form-control" id="email" name="email"
                                    placeholder="Enter Username" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group input-sm ignore">
                                <label class="input-group-addon ingore" for="password"><i
                                    class=" glyphicon glyphicon-lock ingore"></i></label> <input
                                    type="password" class="form-control ignore" id="password"
                                    name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                                value="${_csrf.token}" />

                            <div class="form-actions">
                                <input type="submit"
                                    class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-default" value="Log in">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Regards,
Mathieu

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `ignore` class on `input`, but not `label`.

[update]
Are you using [jquery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)? If yes, you should only set the validation rules in the html or just in js. You have rules like `required` and `min` in html elements, and also in js rules. I am not sure which one will be used. But you should only use one way.

Comment: It has...
class="form-control ignore"

ignore class were added into lables later as an act of desperation

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the trouble. I have switched to the newest plugin and all problems were solved.

Thanks for helping me.

M